# Am I using negative indices wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’m doing a coding exercise and it want’s me to use negative indicates to access a variable called ellies_score. I did this and it is telling me I’m not using negative indicates. Here is the code:

```
class_name_test = [['Jenny', 90], ['Alexus', 85.5], ['Sam', 83], ['Ellie', 101.5], ['Bob', 87.6]]

ellies_score = class_name_test[-2] [-1]
print(ellies_score)
```

I don’t know if I might have misspelled the

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: could you please consider to update your question to include the python response that shows "telling me I’m not using negative indicates" ?

Comment: Try `class_name_test[-2][-1]` instead. The code is identical from the perspective of the interpreter, but a bad auto-checker might be getting tripped up by the unnecessary space that you're using. It's impossible for it to determine whether or not you're using negative indices from just looking at the output, so it must be checking the code itself to determine that.

Comment: Thanks Carcigenicate! Sorry I don’t know how to mark the question as solved but it is now!

Comment: @Carcigenicate should post that as an answer, so that you _can_ accept it.

Comment: Now that I'm aware that that was the fix I can! I wasn't going to create a random guess answer when this was first asked.

Comment: Maybe a link to the coding exercise site would also be nice so we know where to stay away from :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a grader can't tell what indices you used by looking solely at the output, it must be analyzing the code itself. Unfortunately, auto-graders are often simplistic and unforgiving of things like extra spacing that they didn't account for.

```
class_name_test[-2] [-1]
```

This has a superfluous, uncommon space between the `[-2]` and `[-1]`, which may be throwing off the checker. I would remove that space to appease the checker, and because I don't believe that helps readability or is encouraged by any style guide I've ever seen.